# Have a unique check-run for github actions workflow

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I'm trying to enforce labelling PR's using [enforce-label-action](https://github.com/yogevbd/enforce-label-action).

```yaml
name: Enforce PR label

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled, unlabeled, opened, edited]

jobs:
  enforce-label:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: yogevbd/enforce-label-action@master
      with:
        REQUIRED_LABELS_ANY: "bug,enhancement,feature"
```

The problem is that each time PR is labeled, a new check-run getting created and the old one's still having a failing status which cause the check-suite to show: `Some checks were not successful`.

Is it possible for `github-actions` to discard the old check-runs when a workflow check with the same name is getting triggered?

[image: check-runs status]

Comment: Interesting problem. Have you tried removing `types: [labeled, unlabeled, opened, edited]` and just using `on: pull_request`?

Comment: Yes. Did not help and didn't trigger again on label change.

Comment: This might not be intended behavior. It might be worth reaching out to GitHub support about this one.

Comment: Try to add push:

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled, unlabeled, opened, edited]

Comment: There is a action for that:

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/enforce-pr-label

Comment: This is no longer an issue.. Looks like github fixed it by now.

Comment: If its fixed I suggest this question is no more use to the public and you should close it. Great you solved it, though, and thanks for coming back to update it!

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed, it was a bug on GitHubs end.