# Hide Github Action when completed on Pull Request

Tags: github, pull-request, github-actions, octokit, octokit-js

I have a GitHub action that evaluates something and then creates a Status Check with the result.
`setup` is the one that evaluates and `linting` is the result (a different status check with all the information). This is done because the *default* status check is only the logs, but if I create a second one, I can format it with Markdown.

The problem I have is that, when the action is executed to the same commit (because the Pull Request was modified by changing title, reviewers, etc) the action is executed again, which is intended, but creates a second `setup` check that doesn't disappear. This will accumulate for as many modifications I make.

The old `linting` status check, instead, will be replaced by the new one, so I don't have any problem with that.

[image]

Is there any way to hide the `setup` check once it's completed? Or to completely hide it? I would prefer to show it while it's running, but once it's finished it should hide itself to keep the PR clean.

Comment: when you say "then creates a Status Check" do you use the commit status API or the checks API? is `action/ setup (pull_request)` the one you create or are these created automatically by action runs?

Comment: @Gregor I use the checks API. `setup` is the one created by the action run. `linting` is the check I create using the checks API.

Comment: I would say this is a bug. I'd write support@github.com about it. I agree that the behavior should be the same as it is with checks / commit status, where a check with the same name (context) gets replaced by the new one

Comment: If its the same bug as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026218/have-a-unique-check-run-for-github-actions-workflow then this is a duplicate and its fixed and can be closed.